# Using C# SerialPort Class - How do I reset a Freedom Board via usb/serial?

Tags: c#, windows, serial-port, mbed

I currently am working on a project using a Freescale FRDM-KL25Z in the MBED environment. Per their instructions I started by using Tera Term to communicate with the Freedom board via the virtual serial port over USB. Using Tera Term, when I first connect to the Freedom board I have to either press the RESET button on the board or in Tera Term select Control->Send Break to initiate communications.

Now I want to create a better PC user interface using Visual Studio and C#. The one thing I cannot figure how to do however, is to reset the Freedom board from C#. I am working from the assumption that the SerialPort class is what I need to communicate to the Freedom board and that seems to work fine. And I also assumed that setting the BreakState and resetting the BreakState would perform the same function as the Tera Term function, but whenever I try to perform

comPort.BreakState = true;

I get an IOException with the message (extracted with a try-catch of the exception) of "A device attached to the system is not functioning." which is not really helpful to me because I have no idea what is wrong. The SerialPort works fine (except for BreakState) using C# if I reset from the Freedom board's button.

So my questions:

1. Is BreakState what I want to reset the Freedom board? I am assuming that BreakState generates a Break signal and that that is what Tera Term does.
2. If it is, how does one use it without getting an exception?
3. If it is not, then how do you perform that function?

I am at a loss as I have googled everything I can think of and have made no progress in solving this. I am adding a reset button to my device but I still want a software solution since I believe that it can be done, since Tera Term does it.

Comment: Use an API monitor to see the actual function that's failing and its return code.  Sysinternals' Port Monitor would be a good choice but I don't think they ever made a 64-bit version.

Comment: Using `dotPeek` it looks like setting `BreakState` causes a straightforward call to `SetCommBreak`.  Unfortunately the error reporting helper function `System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError` discards the actual error :(

Comment: After reading your posts I search for SetCommBreak to see if there was any information there and I found in an answer to a post at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585661/sending-serial-break-using-windows-xp-api) the following "By choosing a slower baud rate and sending a zero, you end up holding the line at zero for longer than the receiver expects a byte to be, so it interprets it as a break." which I tried. It does in fact reset my Freedom Board. I miss the initial text that is sent at board start up but that is ok. I would still like to know why BreakState doesn't work.

Comment: That's why monitoring API calls is so important -- you can see what Tera Term does differently.

Comment: The message "A device attached to the system is not functioning" may mean that you use a chinese cheap USB to RS232 converter chip (e.g.  CH340) which comes with a buggy chinese driver which is programmed so sloppy that setting a break is simply not implemented and the driver returns this error.